# Organize by the element of a tuple in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I want to organize by the element of tuple in a dictionary.

I am writing a function that organize the element of tuple

```
grade = {'A+': 4.3, 'A': 4.0, 'A-': 3.7,
       'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7,
       'C+': 2.3, 'C': 2.0, 'C-': 1.7,
       'D+': 1.3, 'D': 1.0, 'D-': 0.7,
       'F' : 0.0}


subject = {'math':  {('Tom', 'A+'), ('Kevin','B+')},
       'History':  {('Kate', 'C+'),('Eric','C'),('Hannah','A-')}, 
       'English':  {('Eli', 'B-')}}`
```

I want output like

```
{'A': {'math':{'Tom'}, 'history': {'Hannah'}}, 
  'B':{'math': {'Kevin'}, 'English': {'Eli'}}, 
  'C':{'History': {'Kate', 'Eric'}}}
```

I can't figure out how to remove suffix and organize by element..
I assume I need several dictionaries and lambdas

Comment: The `grade dict` is not very useful anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict


subject = {'math':  {('Tom', 'A+'), ('Kevin','B+')},
       'History':  {('Kate', 'C+'),('Eric','C'),('Hannah','A-')}, 
       'English':  {('Eli', 'B-')}}

result = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in subject.items():
    for name, grade in v:
        result[grade.rstrip("+-")].setdefault(k, set()).add(name)    #Use rstrip to strip + - 
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'A': {'math': {'Tom'}, 'History': {'Hannah'}}, 
                             'B': {'math': {'Kevin'}, 'English': {'Eli'}}, 
                             'C': {'History': {'Kate', 'Eric'}}
                             })
```